# Is It possible to click through a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` over a `LinearLayout`. There are clickable elements in the `LinearLayout` and since the `ListView` is transparent I can see those elements, and would like to be able to click on them, but even though the `ListView` looks transparent, it behaves as a barrier and doesn't let me click on the elements.

Is there a way I can click through the `ListView`?

If I change the `ListView` `layout_height` to `wrap_content`, it behaves as I want, but I need it to start with a certain height, so the items will stack at the bottom with `android:stackFromBottom="true"`.

This is an example of how the code looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            (Clickable elements)
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="361dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend listview and override the onTouch() method and pass it down to the underlying views

Comment: Your comment was the inspiration for the solution. Ended up coding a `mListView.setOnTouchListener` that passes the event with a `container.dispatchTouchEvent(event);` Thanks for the answer!